# Is it possible to pull from the API a list of YouTube users and channels that have been banned by YouTube because of too many takedown notices, etc.?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We need to create automatic filter for the videos, so that if the owner/channel of videos is banned on youtube, we can remove it from our site as well.

So, Is it possible to pull from the API a list of users and channels that have been banned ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to obtain that information from any of the YouTube APIs.

If you're embedding videos on your site and you want to remove embeds of videos that are unplayable, I'd recommend listening for the [`onError` event](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onError) that the player triggers when a video is unavailable, and logging those failed playbacks somewhere on your end. It's not an exact science, because playbacks might fail due to region restrictions that don't apply to all viewers, for instance, so you'd have to come up with some sort of threshold of failed playbacks that you considered meaningful.